# Python split a string using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, split

I would like to split a string by ':' and ' ' characters. However, i would like to ignore two spaces '  ' and  two colons '::'. for e.g.

```
text = "s:11011 i:11010 ::110011  :110010 d:11000"
```

should split into

```
[s,11011,i,11010,:,110011, ,110010,d,11000]
```

after following the Regular Expressions HOWTO on the python website, i managed to comeup with the following

```
regx= re.compile('([\s:]|[^\s\s]|[^::])')
regx.split(text)
```

However this does not work as intended as it splits on the : and spaces, but it still includes the ':' and ' ' in the split.

```
[s,:,11011, ,i,:,11010, ,:,:,110011, , :,110010, ,d,:,11000]
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:** In case of a double space, i only want one space to appear

Comment: if you want to avoid double space why is there a space in the list you provided as the expected output? also are you looking for a regex answer only?

Comment: sorry i meant that in case of a double space, i only want one space to appear. and no the solution doesnt have to be a regex answer

Comment: this pattern is look like ((\s?).(:)[0-1]+)*---> split groups 1 and groups 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note this assumes that your data has format like `X:101010`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(.+?):(.+?)\b ?',text)
[('s', '11011'), ('i', '11010'), (':', '110011'), (' ', '110010'), ('d', '11000')]
```

Then `chain` them up:

```
>>> list(itertools.chain(*_))
['s', '11011', 'i', '11010', ':', '110011', ' ', '110010', 'd', '11000']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> text = "s:11011 i:11010 ::110011  :110010 d:11000"
>>> [x for x in re.split(r":(:)?|\s(\s)?", text) if x]
['s', '11011', 'i', '11010', ':', '110011', ' ', '110010', 'd', '11000']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the regex `(?<=\d) |:(?=\d)` to split:

```
>>> text = "s:11011 i:11010 ::110011  :110010 d:11000"
>>> result = re.split(r"(?<=\d) |:(?=\d)", text)
>>> result
['s', '11011', 'i', '11010', ':', '110011', ' ', '110010', 'd', '11000']
```

This will split on:

`(?<=\d)` a space, when there is a digit on the left. To check this I use a [lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

`:(?=\d)` a colon, when there is a digit on the right. To check this I use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this pattern:

```
([a-z\:\s])\:(\d+)
```

It will give you the same array you are expecting. No need to use split, just access the matches you have returned by the regex engine.

Hope it helps!